# statements in android click listener not executing immediately if followed by large code

Tags: android

If i have some function call which takes some time to execute and return inside the onclick listener of a button, the first line of the onclick listener executes only after the function call execution is done.

example:
 Here i could see the toast only after the function `somefunction()` finishes executing.

```
shareButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    //@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
      Toast.makeText(con,"hi",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      somefunction()//takes sometime to execute and return
    }
}
```

Comment: Of course it wouldn't. Heavy work is not suggested in main thread. Use a different thread for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason this is happening is because when you call `show()` on a `Toast` (and this goes for most UI updates), the application puts the view update at the end of the main thread's execution queue. To achieve what you want, post `someFunction()` at the end of the queue in the following way.

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    Toast.makeText(con, "hi", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    new Handler().post(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            somefunction();
        }
    });
}
```

Of course, if `someFunction()` is causing an even slightly noticeable UI delay, it's recommended you run it on a separate thread.